# React Native: useNavigation returns different objects

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am facing some troubles with react-navigation.
Here is App.tsx:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>()
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function Root() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="ראשי" component={Dashboard} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="היסטוריית קריאות" component={History} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="התנתק" component={Home} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <NavigationContainer >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions= {{headerShown:false}}>
            <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown:false}} name="Root" component={Root} /> 
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Stack.Screen name="History" component={History} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </View>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```

The first screen to load is "Dashboard".
Dashboard.tsx:

```
export default function Dashboard({navigation}:{navigation: any}) {
  
    const navigation_drawer = useNavigation<DrawerNavigationProp<ParamListBase>>()
    console.log(navigation_drawer)

    return (
        
        <View>
            ...
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation_drawer.openDrawer()} style={styles.hamburgerIconWrapper}>
                    <Icon name="menu" size={32}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ...
       </View>
    )
}
```

When pressing `TouchableOpacity`, a side drawer opens as expected.
If I navigate to other page and then come back to Dashboard.tsx, pressing the same element generates the error: `TypeError: navigation_drawer.openDrawer is not a function. (In 'navigation_drawer.openDrawer()', 'navigation_drawer.openDrawer' is undefined)`

After debugging I noticed that when Dashboard is opened for the first time, this is `navigation_drawer`:
`{"addListener": [Function addListener], "canGoBack": [Function canGoBack], "closeDrawer": [Function anonymous], "dispatch": [Function dispatch], "getId": [Function getId], "getParent": [Function getParent], "getState": [Function anonymous], "goBack": [Function anonymous], "isFocused": [Function isFocused], "jumpTo": [Function anonymous], "navigate": [Function anonymous], "openDrawer": [Function anonymous], "pop": [Function anonymous], "popToTop": [Function anonymous], "push": [Function anonymous], "removeListener": [Function removeListener], "replace": [Function anonymous], "reset": [Function anonymous], "setOptions": [Function setOptions], "setParams": [Function anonymous], "toggleDrawer": [Function anonymous]}`
**(openDrawer works)**
But after navigating to other screen through the drawer and coming back to Dashboard through `navigation.navigate('Dashboard');`, this is the value of `navigation_drawer`:
`{"addListener": [Function addListener], "canGoBack": [Function canGoBack], "dispatch": [Function dispatch], "getId": [Function getId], "getParent": [Function getParent], "getState": [Function anonymous], "goBack": [Function anonymous], "isFocused": [Function isFocused], "navigate": [Function anonymous], "pop": [Function anonymous], "popToTop": [Function anonymous], "push": [Function anonymous], "removeListener": [Function removeListener], "replace": [Function anonymous], "reset": [Function anonymous], "setOptions": [Function setOptions], "setParams": [Function anonymous]}` 
**(openDrawer DOESNT work)**
Note that `openDrawer, closeDrawer, and toggleDrawer` methods are missing.
Why is that happening?

Comment: Looks like you have two screens (with different names) that are displaying your Dashboard component. The one named "ראשי" DO HAVE access to the drawer since the one named "Dashboard" DO NOT. Is that make sense to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two sceens (`ראשי` and `Dashboard`) that are displaying the same `Dashboard` component. In your case:

- `ראשי` DO NOT have access to the `drawer`
- `Dashboard` DO HAVE access to the `drawer`

Consider doing something like this (depending on your business logic):

```js
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function Root() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      {* 1. Update Dashboard name. This one DO HAVE access to drawer *}
      <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={Root} /> 
            {* 2. Remove the line bellow since it DO NOT have access to drawer *}
            {* <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} /> *}
          </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```